# Using rsync to sync remote server but before that create restore point

Tags: rsync

I am using `rsync` to sync a remote server as revision diff of repo for continuous integration, which is working great .

a). `export_diff.sh src/revNo`

b). `rsync -avz -e "ssh -i  $ssh_key" --progress ./ src/revNO/  $ssh_user:$target`

This is hot-fixing. If I encounter an issue I dont have way to revert the changes.

Is there a better way to revert hotfix changes or any other suggestions would be great.